# RoR how to pass app id in params via javascript function

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, controller, parameters

There must be an easy answer to this question, but I'm still unable to get it working.

I have a Ruby On Rails app that allows the user to manage projects with a database (create, update, show, edit, destroy, …, etc.). For example, when the user edits a projects, she/he is taken to a page, like http://:3000/projects/3/edit where she/he can modify entries the the form there. Notice the user is editing project 3 in this example.

To edit a project, the user click this button

```
<td><%= button_to 'Edit', { :action => "edit", :id => project }, :method => :get %></td>
```

which call this method

```
# GET /projects/1/edit
def edit
  @project = Project.find(params[:id])
end
```

and that works fine.

However, I added another method call updateFields, so that when a field is modified, a javascript function called updateFields is run and calls an AJAX request that modifies other related fields in the form. The following is an excerpt from updateFields:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function updateFields(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "<%= update_fields_projects_url %>",
        data: {
            project_year: $('.project_year_class').val(),
            project_type: $('.project_type_class').val(),

            <snip>

        }
    });
}
</script>
```

In the controller, I can then get all the info I need in params array, like the following:

```
# PUT /projects/1
# PUT /projects/1.json

def update_fields

  @project = Project.find(params[:project])
  @project_year = params[:project_year]
  @project_type = params[:project_type]

  <snip>

  respond_to do |format|
    if @project.update_attributes(params[:project])
      format.js
      format.html
    else
      format.html { render :action => "update" }
      format.json { render :json => @project.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

The problem I have is that I'm not able to update the form, and on the server, I see the following error messages

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Project without an ID):
app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:101:in `update_fields'

Rendered /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.5ms)
Rendered /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (2.2ms)
Rendered /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (10.8ms)
```

If I specify the project id directly, all works fine

```
@project = Project.find(3)
```

My question is how do I get that id passed in params to the controller by the javascript function in the same way than project_year and project_type? in this example, it is 3, but it will be different for every project because it is assigned when the project is created.

Update1

```
<%= form_for(@project, :html => {:name => "ProjectInfo"}) do |f| %>

  <input type=button id=project_info_button_id value="Show Details" onclick="showHideDiv('project_info_id','project_info_button_id');">

  <div class="form input", id='project_info_id', style='display:none'>
    <% concat "Project Year" %>
    <%= f.text_field :ProjectYear, {:class=>"project_year_class", :Size=>6, :style=>"text-align:right"} %>

    <snip>

  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: can you post the output of the params in the update_field action of your controller? (`puts params.inspect`)

Comment: Thanks MrYoshiji for your prompt answer. params.inspect outputs all the parameters that I explicitly passed into the javascript function but none of them is the project id because I can't figure out the correct syntax for that. I'd appreciate if you can help me with that syntax. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the project id in the data section of the ajax request:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function updateFields(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "<%= update_fields_projects_url %>",
        data: {
            project_year: $('.project_year_class').val(),
            project_type: $('.project_type_class').val(),
            id: <%= @project.id %>,
            <snip>

        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ProjectsController` is trying to find the correct `Project` but you aren’t specifying any ID. You should add an `id` value to the `$.ajax`’s `data` value that specifies the project ID, then change the `find` to be for `params[:id]`.

As an aside, you shouldn’t need an extra `update_fields` method to handle updates to a `Project`. Rails will route any `PUT` to `/projects/:id` to the `ProjectsController`’s `update` method (assuming you have `resources :projects` in your routes file). Instead of pointing `$.ajax` at `update_fields_projects_url` you would use `project_url(project)` (or whatever variable you’re storing the project in) and you wouldn’t have to manually include the project ID.

More on that: you’re bypassing the default way Rails allows you to update resources, which means you’re doing a lot of work manually that you don’t need to.

In the view, use a form helper:

```
<%= form_for @project do |project_form| %>
    <%= project_form.text_field :year %>
    <%= project_form.text_field :type %>
<%= end %>
```

Then you only need to work on the `update` method in the controller, which you have mostly written in the `update_fields`:

```
def update_fields

  @project = Project.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @project.update_attributes(params[:project])
      format.js
      format.html
    else
      format.html { render :action => "update" }
      format.json { render :json => @project.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

When you do it this way, the `form_for` will build text fields that result in the controller getting everything within `params[:project]`. You don’t have to manually extract each attribute and apply it, you get it all for free.

Comment: Thanks Buck for your prompt response. I tried to add id: $(this).attr('project') to the data list, but it did not work ; I guess my syntax is incorrect, so what is the correct syntax to get that "3" there? Can you please help?

Comment: You haven’t shown enough of the view-rendering for me to be able to be specific. Assuming you’re correct that `$(this).attr('project')` will actually return the project ID, just add it to the `data` argument like this: `id: $(this).attr('project')`. However, there are other flaws with your approach. You’re manually setting the project year and type in the AJAX request and then extracting them manually on the server (but never doing anything with them). Why? Why not use the built-in Rails way of creating forms? I’ll update my answer with suggestions.

Comment: Thanks again Buck for the suggestions.
$(this).attr('project') $(this).attr('id') do not pass the right id.
I guess I did not do it the right way from the beginning and now there is a lot of changes and tests I need to perform. I'll do that in a 2nd step. For now, all I need to move forward is how to get the project id passed to updateFields?
I updated my post with more info (Update1)

Comment: This is sloppy, but try: `id: <%= @project.id %>`.